# Apple Mach-O Linker Error after adding chartboost framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, linker, gamekit

I had a working spritekit iOS project. After import of Chartboost framework and its dependencies, i got the following error:

> ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/Kalai/Desktop/Caveman
>   Crush/codecanyon-12618173-fast-run/GP/GameKit.framework/GameKit,
>   missing required architecture x86_64 in file
>   /Users/Kalai/Desktop/Caveman
>   Crush/codecanyon-12618173-fast-run/GP/GameKit.framework/GameKit (3
>   slices) Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GKGameCenterViewController", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in GameViewController.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GKLocalPlayer", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in GameViewController.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit
>   code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Before chartboost.framework integration, the only framework included was gamekit.framework. The strange thing is even after removing chartboost and its dependencies, i still get the error and unable to compile. I am using xcode 8. Any help?

Comment: Have you tried to clean the project and the rebuild?

Comment: @Rashwan, Yes. That's the first thing i did. I have tried restarting xcode and even Mac but doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out finally. Gamekit.framework was duplicated and stored inside the project folder. When I delete it, everything works fine.